# Excel Macro for Combining Different Values in a Cell of a Column

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to create a macro where I have this excel spreadsheet with the same values in a row but different values for a column and I want it to put it on a single column using macro.
for example;

`A      B
TEST   1
TEST   2
TEST   3`

Result:

`A      B
TEST   1,2,3`

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, I suggest you yo read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question in order to help us to understand your problem and see what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways to do this but this is a pretty simple solution:

```
Sub consolidateValues()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rw In Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range("A:B")).Rows

        'Skip row 1 (assumed headers)
        If rw.Row <> 1 Then

            s = ""

            For i = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count To rw.Row + 1 Step -1

                If rw.Cells(1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 1) Then
                    s = sh.Cells(i, 2).Value & IIf(s = "", "", ",") & s
                    sh.Rows(i).Delete
                End If

            Next i

            If s <> "" Then rw.Cells(1, 2).Value = rw.Cells(1, 2).Value & "," & s

        End If

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

notes : 
1. D1 in line Set xRg = Range("D1") means that the result will be placed in cell D1.

2. No and Combined Color in line xRes(1, 1) = "No" and xRes(1, 2) = "Combined Color" are the headers of concatenated columns. You can change them as you need.
3. Press the F5 key to run the code, then you will get the concatenated results in specified range.

   ```
    Sub ConcatenateCellsIfSameValues()
    Dim xCol As New Collection
    Dim xSrc As Variant
    Dim xRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    xSrc    = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
    Set xRg = Range("D1")
    On Error Resume Next
    For I = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
    xCol.Add xSrc(I, 1), TypeName(xSrc(I, 1)) & CStr(xSrc(I, 1))
    Next I
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim xRes(1 To xCol.Count + 1, 1 To 2)
    xRes(1, 1) = "No"
    xRes(1, 2) = "Combined Color"
    For I = 1 To xCol.Count
    xRes(I + 1, 1) = xCol(I)
    For J = 2 To UBound(xSrc)
       If xSrc(J, 1) = xRes(I + 1, 1) Then
           xRes(I + 1, 2) = xRes(I + 1, 2) & ", " & xSrc(J, 2)
       End If
    Next J
    xRes(I + 1, 2) = Mid(xRes(I + 1, 2), 2)
    Next I
    Set xRg = xRg.Resize(UBound(xRes, 1), UBound(xRes, 2))
    xRg.NumberFormat = "@"
    xRg = xRes
    xRg.EntireColumn.AutoFit  
    End Sub
   ```

Comment: This only produced `2, 3` for `TEST` on the first line.